# I can not create new rails app without running /bin/bash --login command first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My ruby was 3.0.2, and I upgraded my ruby version to 3.2.2 but when I try to create new rails app I get the following error.
/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby3.0’: No such file or directory
So, I run "/bin/bash --login" everytime I create the rails app and access rvm. I want to create rails app the same old way without /bin/bash --login command first. What I'm I supposed to do?

I  rvm use 3.2.2 --default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your terminal to use a "Login Shell".  This works differently depending on which os / terminal emulator you are using.

On MacOS using iTerm2 you have to go to Profiles -> Open Profiles.. select the profile you are using then Edit Profiles.. and change Command to "Login Shell".

I'm not sure how to do this in other shell emulators but this should get you started.